# Displaying content of Component that i fetched with @ContentChildren or @ViewChild

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular10

So I'm trying to display child components at specific locations in my Component.

I have the following:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-list',
  template: `
<p *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item.order}}
  <!-- display content of child component here -->
</p>`
})
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  //Get all child components of the type ItemComponent and store them.
  @ContentChildren(ItemComponent, {descendants: true}) 
  items?: QueryList<ItemComponent>;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
    
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
      
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  template: `
<p>
  item works!
</p>
<ng-content></ng-content>
`
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() order?: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I tried to display it using `<ng-content select="item">` but that didn't work.

With the following:

```html
<app-item-list>
  <app-item order="2">
    test2
  </app-item>
  <app-item order="1">
    test1
  </app-item>
</app-item-list>
```

the expected output is

```
2
item works!
test2
1
item works!
test1
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2aibgt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can suggest you a solution that is used in Angular material library.

- Wrap content of `app-item` component in `<ng-template>` tag

**item.component.html**

```
<ng-template>  <----------------------------- wrapper
  <p>
    item works!
  </p>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

- then we can grab a reference to that `TemplateRef`

**item.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild(TemplateRef, {static: true}) template: TemplateRef<any>;
```

- finally we can use it in a loop of `app-item-list` component

**item-list.component.html**

```
<p *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item.order}}
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.template"></ng-template>
</p>
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j6yhe8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks this did what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

There is really no way to achieve this using `ng-content` (as far as I know).
`ng-content` is for static content projection only.

Have a look at the use case here - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563 - paragraph 2 confirms the fact that you have to use a query with viewref to do what you want to do i.e. the solution that @yurzui provided.

You can always use the selector to statically select which part of the content you want to project, but I suspect this is not what you're looking for:

```
<ng-content select="[order=2]">
</ng-content>
<ng-content select="[order=1]">
</ng-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may missed add `select` item reference variable in `item-list.component.html`

**item.component.html**

```
<p>item works</p>
<ng-content select="[body]">
</ng-content>
```

**item-list.component.html**

```
<p *ngFor="let item of items">
  <app-item >
  <div body>
      {{item.order}}
  </div>
  </app-item>
  test2
</p>
```

Ref: [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pvobun?file=src%2Fapp%2Fitem-list%2Fitem-list.component.html)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7jcbze). Ealier I thought there was not way to achieve your output but I finally figured it out.

What I did was eliminate the `@ContentChildren` approach and instead replaced it with an `items Input` passed from the `app` component. I iterated through the items, displaying the order and the corresponding `app-item` component.

Comment: Please explain in your answer what you did. It will help the questioner as well the community.

Comment: Sadly this is not a solution that matches what I'm after i want to use angular markup to define the content.